# How do I get specific users from UserProfile

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following model classes.

Here's UserProfile model of my "users" app. It's a ProfileModel for Django's (django.contrib.auth) User app.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from apps.programs.models import Program

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, primary_key=True)
    USER_TYPES = (
        ('STUD', 'Students'),
        ('INST', 'Instructors'),
        ('ADV', 'Advisers'),
        ('BRAN', 'Branch Workers')
    )
    status = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=USER_TYPES)
    program = models.ForeignKey(Program)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s %s' % (self.user, self.status, self.program)
```

Here's my Course model of my "courses" app.

```
from django.db import models
from apps.programs.models import Program
from apps.users.models import UserProfile


class Course(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=6, primary_key=True)
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    course_language = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    credit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=1)
    schedule = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    program = models.ForeignKey(Program)
    SEMESTER = (
        ('f', 'Fall Semester'),
        ('s', 'Spring Semester'),
        ('b', 'Both Semesters'))
    semester = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SEMESTER, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

And here's my InstructorCourse model of my "courses" app, where I'm going to store some courses leaded by some instructors. The "course" field is connected with Course model and the "instructor" with UserProfile model. And here's the problem.

```
class InstructorCourse(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, name='course_name')
    instructor = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, name='instructor_username')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s %s" % (self.course_name, self.instructor_name)
```

The problem is that when I try to add an instructor in admin, I get all users in a system, because instructor fields takes UserProfile and get all users. But it is not what I want. I need users only with 'INST' value of 'status' field from UserProfile model. May someone help me with that? Should I create my own Manager for InstructorCourse model? Or what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding this correctly, you want to limit the options for setting the instructor on the `InstructorCourse` model.

I think you can accomplish this with adding something like `limit_choices_to={'status': 'INST'}` into your `InstructorCourse` model.

[take a look at `limit_choices_to` from the django docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to)

```
class InstructorCourse(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, name='course_name')
    instructor = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, name='instructor_username', limit_choices_to={'status': 'INST'})

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s %s" % (self.course_name, self.instructor_name)
```